# manyone field con un valor por defecto predeterminado, Odoo14

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

Tengo el modelo `sale.order` que tiene el campo `partner_shipping_id.country_id` del modelo `res.country`, lo que quiero es saber cómo tener un nuevo campo many2one (res.country) pero con el campo `sale_order.partner_shipping_id.country_id` cargado por defecto.

He intentado de estas formas sin poder obtener el resultado:

```
def _default_country_edit(self):
    return self.partner_shipping_id.country_id

country_edit = fields.Many2one('res.country', string="País", default=lambda self: self._default_country_edit())
```

esta:

```
country_edit = fields.Many2one('res.country', string="País", default=_default_country_edit())
```

pero no carga el valor x default, lo que necesito es tener algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Odoo14

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice sobreescribir el metodo `read`, si no tiene el nuevo campo, setearlo y listo.

```
if not self.country_edit:
   self.country_edit = self.partner_shipping_id.country_id
```

Obviamente en el metodo write se debe setear el campo `sale_order.partner_shipping_id.country_id` con el nuevo.